# Is there an FX aggregator pedal that allows A/B/Y for 2 outputs?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I recently bought and set up the Boss ES8 and was very disappointed to realize that even though it has 2 outputs that can be used individually or at the same time, ALL of the effects route to both outputs when activated. You cannot choose which output to send individual effects to. Obviously, I'm dumb for not figuring that out ahead of time, but now I'm wondering if that capability exists at all.

So, does anybody know of a similar programmable patch pedal that will allow you to assign multiple effects pedals to individual patches, but ALSO allows you to designate which outputs the various individual effects are sent to?

Answer (score 1):

Some of those in/out are stereo, so surely some pedals could be routed left and right. Boss would have to incorporate this because some pedals ( theirs also!) are stereo, and would need routing to two destinations. As I say to myself often, if all else fails, read the instructions...